# What is the reasoning behind the default eps value for the 'SLSQP' method in SciPy's minimize function?

Tags: optimization, scipy

From here:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp

It says that the default value for the `eps` option is `1.4901161193847656e-08`. Why was this value chosen, and not something simpler like `1.5e-08`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This value corresponds to the square root of the machine epsilon ($\sqrt\epsilon_{machine}$). For default float64 numbers, $\epsilon_{machine}=2.220446049250313e-16$ so $\sqrt\epsilon_{machine}=1.4901161193847656e-08$.

You may see [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/choosing-epsilons) for justifications to this choice.